# How to order by nested collection navigation property in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

How to make order by by nested collection property. In my case if student hasn't any marks it give an error that it's needed to have a least one element to order by. How i can order by by CurrentMark?

```
        public IEnumerable<Student> Get(Expression<Func<Student, bool>> expr = null,
        Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>> orderBy = null,
        Func<IQueryable<Student>, IIncludableQueryable<Student, object>> includes = null)
    {
        var repo = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Student>();
        var students= repo.GetPagedList(expr, orderBy, includes)
            .Items;

        return students;
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        Get(expr: null, orderBy: orderBy => orderBy.OrderBy(mark => mark.Marks.OrderBy(curr => curr.CurrMark)));
        //over here i came across an error
    }
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mark
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int CurrMark { get; set; }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        public Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: the CurrMark of which of the marks of a specific student do you want to order by?

Comment: What if you try with something like `mark.Marks.DefaultIfEmpty().OrderBy(`? Untested though

Comment: @DevilSuichiro The question is about ways of ordering navigation property collection

Comment: Please show the *exact* exception message. I'm not sure if you interpret it correctly.

Comment: the navigation property is for a regular left outer join with a table. If you want the collection to be sorted, either do so in memory (after executing the query), or use the .Join extension method with the sorted set.